# Show specific part of background image

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm having a little problem with one of my background images in a div element. I'm using the following CSS:

```
.myBox
{
 background-image:url('....');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}
```

My background image is a picture with some people on it. Now, if I increase the width of my browser window, at a specific point, some of the people are cutted off (due to the automatic resize of the image with 'background-size:cover').

My question is: Is there any option (or jQuery plugin), to set a specific part on the background image that will be always visible on all window sizes and also fill the whole element?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of solutions you could try; however, you might want to start with something simple like applying a background-position.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Using the background image of the group of people as an example, you might set `background-position: top` so that their heads never get cut off. You can also set the vertical and horizontal position in pixel or percent units.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! it helped!

Answer (score -1):

try boostrap3 `img-responsive` class

> .img-responsive   Makes an image responsive (will scale nicely to the
>   parent element)
>   http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question properly. I'm not really aware of a library that can show a specific part of an image, but I do know of CSS shapes which let you define a set of polygons to create any shape of your imagination I think that should give you the advantage you want. If you want more go to this nice tutorial and scroll to the section where he gets an image to display in a leaf shape: http://alistapart.com/article/css-shapes-101#section5